# Find permutation list

Tags: python, algorithm

I have a task. I know this task is really easy but..

A non-empty zero-indexed array A consisting of N integers is given.
A permutation is a sequence containing each element from 1 to N once, and only once.
For example, array A such that:

- A[0] = 4
- A[1] = 1
- A[2] = 3
- A[3] = 2

is a permutation, but array A such that:

- A[0] = 4
- A[1] = 1
- A[2] = 3

is not a permutation.
The goal is to check whether array A is a permutation.

I implemented this solution, but I think this isn't the best solution.

```
def solution(A):
    # write your code in Python 2.6
    maxN = max(A)
    B = list(xrange(1,maxN+1))
    if sorted(A) == sorted(B):
        return 1
    else:
        return 0
```

Do you have any ideas how I should solve this problem?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to generate all permutations of a list in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/104420/how-to-generate-all-permutations-of-a-list-in-python)

Answer (score 3):

```
def solution(A):
    N = len(A)
    return min(A) == 1 and max(A) == N and len(set(A)) == N
```

That takes (expected) time linear in `N`, so is expected to be faster than sorting.  But it does rely on the stated assumption that *all* list entries are in fact integers.  If they're not, then, for example,

```
>>> solution([1, 2, 4, 3.14159])
True
```

Comment: I wonder how bad the runtime can actually get, since hash collisions are somewhat restricted by the fact that we know all elements are between 1 and n.

Comment: @user2357112, nothing in the problem statement says all input elements are between 1 and `n`.  We're only told that the input array contains `N` integers.  In any case, CPython's dicts (& sets) are guaranteed to have no collisions at all if storing a contiguous range of integers (although that's not guaranteed by the docs - it's a fact of the CPython implementation).

Comment: We know all input elements are between 1 and n because we check that `min(A) == 1 and max(A) == N`.

Comment: Ah, OK.  Then, as I said, there are no collisions at all, except on identical values.

Comment: Collisions would have to occur while building the set, before it reaches full size. Elements can still land in the same bucket then.

Comment: Good point!  Now try to find an example where you can actually measure a difference ;-)

Answer (score 0):

What about this?:

```
>>> def is_permutation(a, n):
        if len(a) != n: return False
        h = {}
        for i in a:
            if not 1 <= i <= n: return False
            if h.setdefault(i, False): return False
            h[i] = True
        return True

>>> is_permutation([1,4,2,3], 4)
True
>>> is_permutation([1,4,2,0], 4)
False
>>> is_permutation([1,4,2],4)
False
```

Comment: I'd use an n-length array for the flags, but other than that, the first solution looks good. The second doesn't work; `[2, 2, 2]` is not a permutation.

Comment: If you don't mind, please correct your syntax, `i<2 or i>n` looks really weird. I think that I'll look better with spaces.

Answer (score 0):

If both arrays should have all numbers from 1 to N you shouldn't sort them, all you need to do is make sure they actually have all the numbers.

so this is your algorithm (working solution soon):

1. make sure the list is of size N, otherwise return false.
2. generate list of N zeros (We will refer to it as `zero-list`)
3. for each member (say it's value is `m`) of the list (both) increase the `zero-list[m-1]` by 1
4. make sure all members of `zero-list` is 1

This is O(n) as opposed to O(nlogn) that you have right now.

What you are doing verifies that each member from 1 to N exists in the list you're given

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

def is_perm(l, n):
    # make sure initial criterias are met
    if len(l) != max(l) or len(l) != n:
        return False
    # make room for a list that verifies existence from 1 to N
    zero_list = [0 for i in l]
    # "mark" using the new list each member of the input list
    for i in l:
        try:
            zero_list[i-1] += 1
        except:
            return False

    # make sure all members have been "marked"
    for i in zero_list:
        if zero_list[i] != 1:
            return False

    # if all is good, the earth is saved
    return True

if "__main__" == __name__:
    print is_perm([1, 2, 3, 3], 4) # false
    print is_perm([1, 2, 4, 3], 4) # true
    print is_perm([1, 2, 4, 300000000000000], 4) # false
```

Comment: This algorithm bears a resemblance to one that works, but it doesn't work. Reread the problem statement; there is only one input list.

Comment: What happens for input `[1, 2, 1000000000000000000]`? ;-)

Comment: @TimPeters can you have a look?

Comment: Now what if the input is `[1, 3, -10000000000000]`?

Answer (score 0):

```
def is_perm(lst):
    n = len(lst)
    if min(lst) != 1 or max(lst) != n:
        return False
    cnt = [1] * n
    for e in lst:
        cnt[e - 1] -= 1
    return not any(cnt)
```

It has a worst case complexity `O(n)` which is of course optimal.

Answer (score 0):

Just check if all elements are present ...

```
In [36]: all(map(lambda p: p in [1,4,3,2], range(1,5)))
Out[36]: True
In [37]: all(map(lambda p: p in [1,4,3,2444], range(1,5)))
Out[37]: False
In [38]: all(map(lambda p: p in [1,4,3], range(1,5)))
Out[38]: False
```

Comment: it has a quadratic complexity

Comment: One can just use `imap()` instead of `map()` which returns a lazy iterator, and `all()` is lazy anyway, so we should be able to get much better than the quadratic complexity I think. No need to expressedly code that in these days with lazy evaluation becoming very common in Python. Also makes for code relatively easy to read.

Answer (score 0):

So I found solution which works great:

```
def solution(A):
  A.sort(reverse=True)
  return 1 if A[0] == len(A) and len(set(A)) == len(A) else 0
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is fastest way:

```
def solution(A):
    '''
    >>> solution([4,1,3,2])
    1
    >>> solution([2,3])
    0
    '''
    suma = sum(A)
    N = len(A)
    if (N*(N+1)/2)!=suma:
        return 0

    return 1
```